# How to remove a word that starts with a certain character from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
'here is some #tweet from @someone to @somebody-else'
```

and I need to remove all the words (and-phrases) that start with @mentions and return the string without them, so that it becomes

```
'here is some #tweet from to'
```

How to do that in Javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = 'here is some #tweet from @someone to @somebody-else';

str = str.replace(/\s?@\S+/g, '');
```

Comment: Please explain your answers.

Comment: @RUJordan - it's a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: @SeanBright don't you think if the OP knew what a regular expression was they wouldn't have asked the question? No matter how trivial it seems, all answers should be explained.

Comment: This leaves an extra space, for instance, before "to" in the sample code.  You might want to use `/\s*@\S+/`.

Comment: Additionally, it's helpful to explain your regex when posting it as an answer, since someone who doesn't know regex won't understand what it means.

Comment: @RUJordan OP actually knows what a regular expression is, but he is a bit dumb regarding their use, hence the question. by the way, what's the difference between using S+ and the [\w-]+ below? Thank you!

Comment: `\S+` means 1 or more non-space characters.  `[\w-]+` means 1 or more word characters or hyphens.  [Here is the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that covers the various supported classes.

Comment: I've updated to address the spacing issue that @ScottSauyet brought up

Answer (score 3):

```
var s = 'here is some #tweet from @someone to @somebody-else';
s = s.replace(/\s?@[\w-]+/g, "");
//here is some #tweet from to
```

***DEMO:***

http://regex101.com/r/aV0hF2

Comment: This leaves an extra space, for instance, before "to" in the sample code.  You might want to use `\s*/@[\w-]+/`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet noted, changed, tks.